# Regex assigning multiple groups to keyword

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to implement a regex that has the capability to assign a same keyword or combination of keywords to one or multiple Named Groups.

For example I want to match **('aa' AND 'bb') OR 'cc'** and assign 'aa' AND 'bb' to a group<1> and 'cc' to group<2>.

Also I can have a query like **('aa' AND 'bb') OR 'aa'** and I want 'aa' AND 'bb' to be in group<1> and at the same time 'aa' to be in group<2>.

```
// Works to get 'aa' everywhere but cannot find a way to add 'bb' to the group<1>
(?=(?:\s+|^)(?<1>aa)(?:\s+|$))
```

EDIT :

```
Input Example : bb is nice but not without the missingaa
Output : Does not Validate, Group<1> is null | Group<2> is null
```

-

```
Input Example : bb is nice as well as aa
Output : Validate, Group<1> : bb is nice as well as aa | Group<2> is null
```

-

```
Input Example : bb is nice but not without the missingaa or cc
Output : Validate, Group<1> is null | Group<2> is cc
```

-

```
Input Example : bb is nice as well as aa or cc
Output : Validate, Group<1> is bb is nice as well as aa | Group<2> is cc
```

I know that the grouping might be complicated but I am looking to have Group<1> which is not null if aa and bb exist.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and desired output please? The problem is the input imo. What should the first group match? And when should the second group match?

Comment: What engine are you using that allows a digit for the first char of a group name?  (?<1> ,, )

Comment: I am using .NET C# 4.0/4.5

Comment: And the digit is not important I might as well store the information in a named group (with a specific string)

Comment: I am currently trying to use backreferences but without success yet

Comment: Don't do this.  I know it seems like an obvious approach, but trust me: you're only making the job much more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a point of reference, with most regex engines, Group matches don't accumulate like an array. Dot-Net is an exception which can do that (collections).

My apologies, you were right, it needs the alternation.
However, you have to force find the first OR c. This is done with a conditional lookahead.
Good luck!

```
 # ^.*?(?:(?:(?<grp1>(?:\baa\b.*?\bbb\b|\bbb\b.*?\baa\b))(?(?=.*\b(?:cc|aa)\b).*(?<grp2>(?:\bcc\b|\baa\b))|))|(?<grp2>\b(?:cc|aa)\b))

  ^ 
  .*? 
  (?:
       (?:                           # Force find   a AND b, OR c
            (?<grp1>
                 (?:
                      \b aa \b .*? \b bb \b 
                   |  \b bb \b .*? \b aa \b 
                 )
            )
            (?(?=                  # conditional assertion, force to find 
                 .*
                 \b (?:  cc | aa  ) \b 
              )
                 .* 
                 (?<grp2>
                      \b (?:  cc | aa  ) \b
                 )
              |  
            )
       )
    |  
       (?<grp2>              # Else, forcc find   OR c
            \b (?:  cc | aa  ) \b 
       )
  )
```

Edit: This would match (aa cc), (bb)
But beware, the more  permutations, the more complex. And that leads down the road to assertions, flags, condition's, all of which will slow performance and make maintaining somewhat tougher.

```
 # ^.*?(?:(?:(?<grp1>(?:\baa\b(?:(?!cc).)*?\bbb\b|\baa\b(?:(?!bb).)*?\bcc\b|\bbb\b(?:(?!cc).)*?\baa\b|\bbb\b(?:(?!aa).)*?\bcc\b))(?(?=.*\b(?:aa|bb|cc)\b).*(?<grp2>\b(?:aa|bb|cc)\b)|))|(?<grp2>\b(?:cc|aa)\b))

 ^ 
 .*? 
 (?:
      # Force find:   (aa bb), (cc)
      #               (aa cc), (bb)
      #               (bb aa), (cc)
      #               (bb cc), (aa)
      (?:
           (?<grp1>                                     # GROUP1 
                (?:
                     \b aa \b (?:(?!cc).)*? \b bb \b 
                   |
                     \b aa \b (?:(?!bb).)*? \b cc \b 
                   |
                     \b bb \b (?:(?!cc).)*? \b aa \b 
                   |
                     \b bb \b (?:(?!aa).)*? \b cc \b 
                )
           )

           (?(?=      # Conditional assertion, find   (aa), (bb), (cc) 
                .*
                \b (?:  aa | bb | cc ) \b 
             )
                # The condition is true, so consume it
                .* 
                (?<grp2>                                # GROUP2
                     \b (?:  aa | bb | cc ) \b
                )
             |  # The condition is false, match nothing  
           )

      )
   | 
      # Or, 
      # Force find:   (), (aa)
      #               (), (bb)
      #               (), (cc)

      (?<grp2>                      # GROUP2 
           \b (?:  aa | bb | cc ) \b
      )
 )
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. In fact I am using .NET but I don't think I need to have recursive regex. Would you please check with the examples that I provided?

Comment: Could you please tell me if you find a better solution than this : (?<1>aa.*bb|bb.*aa)|(?<2>cc) as I would like to add probably more members thank only 2 in group1. 
Also if I do (?<1>aa.*bb|bb.*aa)|(?<2>aa) on "aa bb" Group<1> will contain "aa bb" but Group<2> will not contain "aa"  and this is critical to me.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. This is working well for case like "aa bb cc". 
Now one of the complexity of the regex was the fact that I can have "bb aa" so that it requires that I use a prefix (?=) for both "aa" and "bb". Currently "bb aa" cannot be captured. Also by replacing "cc" by "aa" #(?<grp1>.*\baa\b.*\bbb\b)?(?<grp2>.*\b(?:aa)\b)), "aa bb" is only captured in the <grp2> and not both of them.

Comment: @user2465083 - see 'Edit2'. Shouldn't need a (?=) unless you want to get fancy, use alternations like the example for aa.*bb | bb.*aa. Try the simple stuff first to get a working model.

Comment: Thank you again for taking that much time assisting me.
I am sorry but the regex you provided does not match anything on any of the string I tried ("aa bb", "aa bb cc", "cc"...).
I have been able to get the behavior I expect with this (?:(?<grp1>aabb)|(?<grp1>bbaa))|(?<grp2>aa) and the input "aabb aa" but I have not been able to separate the aa bb with any character.
In this example there is 2 matches. A first one with ?<grp1> = "aabb" and ?<grp2> = null and a second with ?<grp1> = null and ?<grp2> = "aa"

Comment: (?:(?<grp1>aa(?:\s+)bb)|(?<grp1>bb(?:\s+)aa))|(?<grp2>aa) - I cannot find a way to say match (?<grp1>aa(?:\s+)bb) (where there is no bb behind). Do you have an idea?

Comment: @user2465083 - You were right a lookahead is needed. I've tested the new edit in Perl. A note - When you process the match, you should reference the capture buffers by name, not by number, as in this case <grp2> is both buffer 2 and 3. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working quite well though I cannot say I understand all of it. I will try to understand it fully tomorrow. I noticed that if I put "aa bb cc" "bb aa cc" this is working wonderfully. Now I would expect "aa cc bb" to create the same groups do you have an idea what can be wrong?

In all cases I will mark your response as valid but if you have more information concerning the ability to move the keywords please let me know.

Tank you again for all the time and effort you took to help me.

Comment: Thank you for all your effort and time to find this solution.

Comment: Your welcome. If you want to make a better pattern, you have to define all the rules of relationships of aa, bb, cc. Try making a logic table and start with what is not possible first, then whats possible. That can then be factored/distilled into a parser.